# illegal instruction while running iperf

Tags: android, shell, android-layout

Enter code herewhile running iperf traffic between an android dut in devkit platform and enet pc connected to ap, **illegal instruction** is returned in the client side, while doing range test by moving ap away from the dut until it disassociates and bringing back towards the dut.

Can anyone help me by telling why this comes and wat to do if it comes? I tried with different versions of iperfs. Still the issue is seen

iperf log:

```
C:\ris>plink -ssh -pw hnd123 svtuser@172.16.11.217 adb shell iperf -c 192.168.1.218 -i 1 -f m -w 512K -t 60 



------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.1.218, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 0.21 MByte (WARNING: requested 0.50 MByte)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.1.217 port 46353 connected with 192.168.1.218 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth

[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  3.58 MBytes  30.0 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  3.72 MBytes  31.2 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  3.77 MBytes  31.7 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  3.85 MBytes  32.3 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  3.99 MBytes  33.5 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  3.98 MBytes  33.4 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  4.02 MBytes  33.8 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  3.84 MBytes  32.2 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  4.04 MBytes  33.9 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  3.93 MBytes  33.0 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 10.0-11.0 sec  4.05 MBytes  34.0 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 11.0-12.0 sec  4.01 MBytes  33.6 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 12.0-13.0 sec  4.02 MBytes  33.7 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 13.0-14.0 sec  4.02 MBytes  33.7 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 14.0-15.0 sec  3.95 MBytes  33.1 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 15.0-16.0 sec  3.88 MBytes  32.6 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 16.0-17.0 sec  4.14 MBytes  34.7 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 17.0-18.0 sec  3.91 MBytes  32.8 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 18.0-19.0 sec  4.05 MBytes  33.9 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 19.0-20.0 sec  3.93 MBytes  33.0 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 20.0-21.0 sec  4.05 MBytes  33.9 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 21.0-22.0 sec  3.93 MBytes  33.0 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 22.0-23.0 sec  3.99 MBytes  33.5 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 23.0-24.0 sec  4.12 MBytes  34.5 Mbits/sec
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3] 24.0-25.0 sec  4.01 MBytes  33.6 Mbits/sec
[1]   Illegal instruction     iperf -c 192.168...
```

Comment: Which iperf version are you using on both sides? iperf 2.0.5 is good.

Comment: i tried using 2.0.5 on both sides and also 2.0.4 on both sides, neither of them worked

Comment: Arun, How did you resolve this? I'm hitting the same issue.

Comment: i didnt find any solution for this. Also i didnt see this issue for a while with latest iperf version.